# Remove file from git commits only

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a file called test.config.php in my git commits that I want to remove this file from my git repo so I used

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD" HEAD
```

but it delete the file from project and git history, I managed to get the file back but I need to delete the file only from git commits not from all the project

Comment: What do you mean that you want to delete the file from the commits, but not the project? Can you make a copy of the file elsewhere, remove it from the commits, and then just copy it back into the project folder?

Comment: The commits *are* the project and the history. If the file is in the commits, it's in Git and in the history. If it's not, it's not. That's all there is to it.

Comment: k i will give it a try thx guys

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git reset --soft HEAD^` this will reset the commit but will keep your changes in your working and index tree, which means that you will find all your changes staged and ready to be committed, also need to note that HEAD^ is a shortcut to HEAD^1 which means that you will get back to the state of the commit that is directly before your current one.

you can also use `git reset --mixed HEAD^` which will remove the commit from the logs and will remove your changes from the index tree meaning that you will find your changes in your working tree only and not staged.